# Sorting by header issue WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, mvvm

I have 2 DataGrids in 2 different views. Both grids are set to:

```
CanUserSort = "True"
```

Grid1 sorts by user clicking on the column header as it should. Grid2 however sorts on some columns but not others. For example I have an ID column, the values are sorted on page load:

1
2
3
4
5

When sorted by clicking on the header, they come back:

2
4
5
1
3

I've also tried `SortMemberPath="ColumnName"`

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="233" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="PublicationsDataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1236" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ModelPublicationsObservableList}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding ModelSelectedPublication}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PublicationIdColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=PublicationId}" Header="PublicationId" Width="80"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PublicationTitleColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=PublicationTitle}" Header="PublicationTitle" Width="350" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PublicationTypeColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=PublicationType}" Header="PublicationType" Width="253" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ProductCodeColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=ProductCode}" Header="ProductCode" Width="216" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dateCreatedColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=DateCreated, StringFormat={}\{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm\}}" Header="DateCreated" Width="SizeToHeader" />                
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="userCreatedColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=userCreated}" Header="UserCreated" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dateUpdatedColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=dateUpdated}" Header="DateUpdated" Width="SizeToHeader" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="userUpdatedColumn" Binding="{Binding Path=userUpdated}" Header="UserUpdated" Width="SizeToHeader" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Post relevant XAML code here.

Comment: Can you show your code attempts so far..

Comment: Edited. CanUserSortColumns is set in the properties window.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but the rows are getting sorted, not the columns individually. So, if you sort by title, your id's will not be sorted. Could this be what you are seeing?

Comment: another thing to consider is that the column has 3 states for sorting 

none , descending , ascending maybe your just transitioning into the "none" state , you can tell be the arrow on the top down , up , and no arrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I've found the culprit. The sorting doesn't work with integer values < 10. I've changed the ID's in my table to 0000001 etc. and everything is fine